# Adding isbn and book title to Access DB in vb.net webform

Tags: asp.net, database, vb.net

I am currently working on a online bookstore for a class using vb.net. I am having trouble adding the isbn and book title to my database. I am able to add author name and email fine, but when I try to do the same I get "duplicate values" error. Here is my source code for adding the book to the database.

```
Imports System
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public Class bookAdded
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        If (Request.QueryString("type") = "delete") Then
            result.Text = "The author " & Request.QueryString("authorName") & " has been deleted."
        Else
            result.Text = "The author " & Request.QueryString("authorName") & " has been added."
            If (Not Page.IsPostBack) Then
                Dim conn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OleDb.12.0;Data Source=" + Server.MapPath("~/bookstore.accdb"))
                conn.Open()
                Dim sql As String = "INSERT INTO books(ISBN, title) VALUES(@isbn, @title)"
                Dim cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand(sql, conn)

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@isbn", Request.QueryString("isbn"))
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@title", Request.QueryString("title"))
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                cmd.Dispose()
                conn.Close()
            End If
        End If
    End Sub

    Protected Sub back_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles back.Click
        Response.Redirect("NextPage.aspx")
    End Sub

    Protected Sub search_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles search.Click
        Response.Redirect("search.aspx")
    End Sub
End Class
```

Your help is much appreciated. Thank you!

P.S: ISBN is a integer and title is a string

Comment: This is probably a separate issue from the question, but OleDb uses `?` placeholders for parameters in the sql instead of `@parameter`. See the example in the docs: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbparameter(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Also: you should re-think using integers for the ISBN. It is occasionally possible for ISBNs to have non-numeric characters (a trailing X). Additionally, newer 13-digit ISBNs can overflow the integer type.

Comment: Finally: Access is very poorly suited for web sites where users can update the information. Performance is not good, and it's only a matter of time before the DB is corrupted. Any in-process DB engine has the same problem. You should be using a server engine like Sql Server or Postgresql for web work.

Comment: Is ISBN the primary key on the table?

Comment: Because of the way this code appears to be called its possible that there are two requests - double clicking on the link that directs the user to the page etc...

Also there are some problems with the code - if you need some advice I'd be happy to give some pointers.